# Внесение информации в базу данных и вытягивание оной из неё же

Tags: java, сервер, библиотеки

Стоит задача:
поднять сервер с бд, с несколькими таблицами, в которые юзеры будут заносить значения. В дальнейшем эти значения нужно будет запрашивать.

Сервер я поставил. Осталось написать простую программу, но в программирование не особо могу (знаю только что такое ооп и как оно работает), поэтому буду обучаться на ходу.

Суть в том, что приложуха нужна только для внутреннего использования в компании, и желательно чтобы она была и на десктоп и на ведройд.

Жава подходит для этого? И насколько сложно это будет реализовать? Может направите в сторону нужных библиотек и подскажите как проще это сделать? Дальше сам разберусь.

Comment: Подходит. Но если не знаешь как и что делать - придется потрать много времени

Answer (score 1):

Если всё так плохо - "в программирование не особо могу", - то MS Access твой выбор!

Answer (score 1):

Я здесь вижу два пути.

**1 - Сделать web приложение.** И с десктопа и с гаджета будет работать в браузере. Этот путь избавляет от изучения андройда.

**Что понадобится:** Знание java, сервлетов, jsp / javascript, html, css. Для базы: например - mysql.

**ПО:** среда разработки, например Intellij idea, контейнер сервлетов - apache tomcat, JDBC драйвер для подключения к базе, сама база.

**2 - Сделать десктопное приложение и приложения для андройд.**

**Что понадобится:** Знание java, sql, android sdk, для gui на компе - javaFx / Swing.

**ПЩ:** среды разработки (Intellij idea, Android studio), JDBC, база (для android - SQlite).

Какой из двух быстрее не знаю, наверное, первый, потому что в андройде много своих тонкостей.

**Вывод:** изучение всего этого не может быть целью создания одного приложения. Может просто обойтись базами данных?